# JToolBar IllegalArgumentException when dropped back into GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, illegalargumentexception

Why does this code throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when the tool bar is dragged off the GUI, then closed (to return it to the GUI)?

I could understand why it might be improper to add a component with no constraint, but in this case, the initial addition of the toolbar to the panel (which uses `GridBagLayout`) without a constraint causes no such problem.  Why should it occur the 2nd and subsequent times it is added?

The code is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21557361/418556), but both codes show the same problem.

### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagToolBarOddity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
                tb.add(new JLabel("Drag me off, then drop me back!"));
                gui.add(tb);

                gui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
                gui.setBackground(Color.RED);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
                f.add(gui);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

### Exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    cannot add to layout: constraints must be a GridBagConstraint
        at java.awt.GridBagLayout.addLayoutComponent(GridBagLayout.java:702)
        at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1120)
        at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicToolBarUI$FrameListener.windowClosing(BasicToolBarUI.java:1265)
        at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2051)
        at javax.swing.JDialog.processWindowEvent(JDialog.java:681)
        at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2009)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Mac OS X 10.9; JDK 7: Works OK with the default `FlowLayout` or `GridLayout`; fails despite `gui.add(tb, new GridBagConstraints())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's snippet from BasicToolBarUI source

```
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent w) {
        if (toolBar.isFloatable()) {
            if (dragWindow != null)
                dragWindow.setVisible(false);
            floating = false;
            if (floatingToolBar == null)
                floatingToolBar = createFloatingWindow(toolBar);
            if (floatingToolBar instanceof Window) ((Window)floatingToolBar).setVisible(false);
            floatingToolBar.getContentPane().remove(toolBar);
            String constraint = constraintBeforeFloating;
            if (toolBar.getOrientation() == JToolBar.HORIZONTAL) {
                if (constraint == "West" || constraint == "East") {
                    constraint = "North";
                }
            } else {
                if (constraint == "North" || constraint == "South") {
                    constraint = "West";
                }
            }
            if (dockingSource == null)
                dockingSource = toolBar.getParent();
            if (propertyListener != null)
                UIManager.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyListener);
            dockingSource.add(toolBar, constraint);
```

As you can see it tries to pass constraintBeforeFloating String as constraint but GridBagLayout expects GridBagConstraints.

```
constraintBeforeFloating = calculateConstraint();
```

and

```
private String calculateConstraint() {
    String constraint = null;
    LayoutManager lm = dockingSource.getLayout();
    if (lm instanceof BorderLayout) {
        constraint = (String)((BorderLayout)lm).getConstraints(toolBar);
    }
    return (constraint != null) ? constraint : constraintBeforeFloating;
}
```

So when floating is closed UI tries to pass curretn constraint (String) to GridBagLayout and fails.

Comment: Thanks.  That about settles it.  :)

Answer (score 3):

From the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html

> For the drag behavior to work correctly, the tool bar must be in a
>   container that uses the BorderLayout layout manager