# Panel for JToolBar with BorderLayout and its height on GridBagLayout JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, border-layout

I have a `JFrame` with `GridBagLayout`. On this frame I have `JToolBar` and `JPanel`. The problem appeared when I dropped tool bar back. In an [answer to JToolBar IllegalArgumentException when dropped back into GridBagLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21564005/3505403) it says that the container for tool bar must be with `BorderLayout`. Ok, I thought and added one more panel (with `BorderLayout`) to frame and tool bar to panel. So I have

> [JFrame [JPanel1[JToolBar]] [JPanel2]]

Everything works. But now I have a problem - I can't set `JPanel1` height so it to be equal to tool bar height and to disappear and appear. I only have weighty as I see, but it's coefficient.

How to solve it?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: @StanislavL All emails on your site are broken. Please update information how to contact with you.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Thank you for help. How can I connect to this person about his code http://java-sl.com/tip_multiple_floatable_toolbars.html ? Can't I do it via stackoverflow?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson And again thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default LayOut of a JFrame is BorderLayout, You just add (set) the JToolBar to JFrame as BorderLayout.NORTH and add JPanel as BorderLayout.CENTER. Set JPanel layout as GridBagLayout and do what you want with it.

I think this is you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your time, nut I need GridBagLayout

Comment: @Andrew Thompson good one :-) this is [available for users with rep >50](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson two upvotes by two *** here :-) you have to know that I'm big fan of *** here, starting with meta community, they won everything, idio*** rulles, phaaaa (for rest or readers discusion by two users without limits)

Comment: BTW - noting this is now the accepted answer prompted me to delete some noise.  Good call!  :)  BTW - welcome to the 'heady world' of those that can comment on any question or answer.  ;)

Comment: Thanks Andrew Thompson and mKorbel.